# Keyboard repeat/delay is reset occasionally in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, keyboard, xorg

My keyboard repeat & delay settings are occasionaly reverted to slow (apparently default) values under Xorg in Ubuntu 18.04.

In this situation, the actual values (as obtained by `xset q`) are

```
auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  30
```

whereas `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay` returns:

```
uint32 250
```

If I afterwards run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250`, the keyboard delay / repeat settings are correctly set (`xset q` then returns `auto repeat delay: 250`).

There seem to be several triggers for the behavior, one reproducibly being a suspend & wakeup cycle; I wasn't able to reproduce others yet.

My system is a rather freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an A10-5800K with an A78M-E35 board in BIOS (non EFI) mode.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. So annoying, definitely not the only place Ubuntu does crap like this. Adding a bounty if anyone has any idea.

Comment: I have a possibly related problem whereby my mouse settings get reverted to some default (too fast for me), but I'm using Kubuntu, it's very random but seems *sometimes* to coincide with closing fullscreen apps (csgo in particular). This sounds like a bug you should probably report.

Comment: Is there a bug report?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a script to automatically reset keyboard repeat rate during resume:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: keyrepeat
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DATE: July 4, 2019.

# NOTE: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086780/keyboard-repeat-delay-is-reset-occasionally-in-ubuntu-18-04

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250
        ;;
esac
```

Place the script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`.

Make it executable with:

```bash
chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/keyrepeat
```

Reboot and then every resume after suspend the command:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250
```

is automatically run.

Comment: Just gsettings didn't work for me. Adding `xset r rate 250 30` did.